# Error de sintaxis SQL usando JPA Criteria Query

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos, jpa

Buenas,

Estoy intentando lanzar una query SQL que me recupere todos los Sites asociados a un usuario, usando el siguiente código JPA:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Site> query = cb.createQuery(Site.class);
Root<Site> fromSite = query.from(Site.class);
Join<UserSiteClientRolePK, Integer> joinUser = fromSite
    .join(Site_.siteClients)
    .join(SiteClient_.usersSitesClientsRoles)
    .join(UserSiteClientRole_.id)
    .join(UserSiteClientRolePK_.userid);
query = query.select(fromSite);
query = query.where(cb.equal(joinUser, userid));
TypedQuery<Site> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);
List<Site> sites = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Sin embargo, al probar el código usando la implementación OpenJPA 2.4.0 obtengo la siguiente excepción en mi test JUnit:

```
<openjpa-2.4.0-r422266:1674604 fatal general error> 
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: 
ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «AND»

Position: 440 {prepstmnt 737085888 
SELECT ...
WHERE (t3.userid = ? AND  AND ) [params=?]} [code=0, state=42601]
```

Por algún motivo, OpenJPA está incluyendo código SQL erroneo "AND AND)" al final del script SQL, y no logro averiguar el motivo.

Me estoy volviendo loco con esto. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme, por favor?

Muchas gracias. Un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Raúl. Este es el sitio en español, por favor publica contenido en español.

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta, disculpa las molestias.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la estructura de las entidades?